# Chrome: Syntax error etc. in javascript console: Any logfile?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It is possible in Google chrome to enable verbose logging; it then even writes console.log-message-calls into a logfile (chrome_debug.log). I was wondering if there is any way or log file of chrome to also capture syntax errors while parsing/running the javascript. Basically, the stuff that you see in the javascript console...

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: you might try using [session storage](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage)

Comment: not sure what your thinking is... yes, you could write some peristent logs with it. but i can already write logs to a file. chrome does. what i dont have is the synatx errors etc that the javascript parser writes...